# MySqlClient ReplicationManager exception

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-express

I set up a test project to connect to a MySQL database (in Visual Studio 2013 Express, using C#). [This is my first time working with SQL.]

I got it working; I can successfully connect to my local database. However, when I copied my connection code to another project, I get the error

> "The type initializer for
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an
>   exception."

My searches about this problem have turned up the solution of enabling "SQL Server Debugging", but this option doesn't seem to exist in the Express versions of Visual Studio.

How can I fix this error in Visual Studio Express? (The project I copied the code to was made in VS2012, if that matters.)

My code (works in my test project, but not in my other project):

```
        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1; userid=newUser1; password=mysql; " +
            "database=pr2_db";
        cn.Open();
```

EDIT: The code works if I start the program without debugging.

Comment: This bug could be related to a number of issues - from the code you posted, it probably doesn't have anything to do with SQL Server Debugging.  Can you provide more information about what version of MySQL you're using and your library version?

Comment: I'm using MySQL version 5.6.25, and the .NET connector version 6.9.6.

Comment: Enabling "native code debugging" in Project -> Properties -> Debug fixes this error. Are there any reasons why I would not want this option turned on?

Comment: It may impact debugging managed code.  Seems like a bug in the MySqlClient ReplicationManager.